# Java - Wait for something to be true

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that runs in the background, and when it hits a certain time a reminder pops up on the computer.

```
 int looplol = 2;
while(looplol != 1){
    if(usertime.equals(time)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usertext);
        looplol = 1;
    }
```

I am trying to make it so it keeps running the program until usertime = time, then it will display the message the user wants and stop the program. This code up here isn't working, does anyone know how I can do this

Comment: what is usertime and time? are they strings? show us more code

Answer (score 0):

This code will make a CPU core spin at 100% until the condition is reached.

If you can work out how long it is between the current time and "user time" (in milliseconds), why not just use `Thread.sleep(ms)`?

```
long userTime = <some time in the future>;
long sleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - userTime;

try {
    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    // Shouldn't happen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `Thread.sleep()`:

```
private void waitUntilSystemTimeMillis(long stopTime) {
    long sleepDuration = stopTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (sleepDuration > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepDuration);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) { 
            throw new RuntimException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
waitUntilSystemTimeMillis(time);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usertext);
```

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 0):

Java util package has a Timer... there you can define an object and when given, invoke a method after a delay...

You can use: `Timer.schedule` for doing something ONCE after a delay

```
Timer t = new Timer("--", true);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usertext");
    }
}, 5000L);
```